# How to run Cython files after compilation?

Tags: cython, setuptools, distutils

My directory structure:

```
/Desktop
    declare.pxd
    foo.pyx
    setup.py
    foo.c
    foo.cpython-38-darwin.so
    /build
        /lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
            foo.cpython-38-darwin.so
        /temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
            foo.o
```

I'm a Cython newcomer. I run the `setup.py` and got those files. I want to run the codes in `foo.pyx` file, how can I do this?

Comment: `foo` is a library, not an executable. Use `import foo` in your own Python code to access it.